# Kotlin cannot access kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1 when calling kotlin function with java lambda

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin

I am trying to call the following Kotlin function from Java

```
override fun First(list: LinqList<ElementType>, condition: (ElementType) -> Boolean) : ElementType
```

like this

```
int first = list.First(list,(x) -> x == 5);
```

but i get the following error

```
Error java: cannot access kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1
  class file for kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1 not found
```

I have tried googling it but i can not find the answer anywhere

Thanks in advance

Comment: First off, the function you defined does not have the same name as the one you're calling (First vs FirstOrDefault).

Comment: How are you compiling your Java project?

Comment: Using gradle and IntelliJ 15 and I fixed the typo

Comment: Does your Java module include the Kotlin runtime in its dependencies? It needs to.

Comment: Yes it does all three jars

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My problem got fixed when I configured Kotlin compiler and runtime for my Java module with the latest stable version (currently 1.3.30)

Just go to **Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin in Project > Android with Gradle** and choose your Java module with **Single module** radio button selected then select your version and **OK**.

Comment: I can't setting it .  I try to create one kotlin.kt file and then do follow IDE ,fix my problem.  [AndroidStudio3.4／kotlin1.3.41／2019-07-08 10:26:19]

Comment: This useful when your project is based on java but you need to use a kotlin based and use its functions inside your java code.

Answer (score 6):

**Another Solution:**

If you have several modules in your android project, please make sure you have added the below config to every module that uses the kotlin:

**Step(1)- Project build.gradle:**

```
// Project build.gradle file.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.30'
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

**Step(2)- Inside each module using kotlin:**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

...

dependencies {
   implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1"
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Reference:
[Add Kotlin to an existing app](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/add-kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

**Android Studio:**

in my case, I have change the signature of the inner function which is making the cause of this exception. try to `clean` your project and run the app, exception will disappear

Answer (score -8):

Method 1) Search for Function1 in your project file and rename it to First.

Method 2) Search for Function1 in your project file and remove all its occurrences.

Comment: Sorry, this is not helpful. The `Function1` class is part of the Kotlin standard library, so neither of your suggestions is applicable.

Comment: This is not the issue