# Removing LeakCanary decompiles unrelated library file, turns a file from .kt to .class

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, decompiling, leakcanary

I was trying to clean my code, as the LeakCanary Library was exposing some android annotations that I was inadvertently using "@NotNull" instead of "@NonNull".

As I finished cleaning the classes (like 30+ classes...), I removed the library entirely:

```
//    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.5'
```

Then the main .kt file of an unrelated library (entirely written in Kotlin) called `CalendarView.kt` https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView.git (a nice customizable calendar) becomes `CalendarView.class`

And the bellow message appears on top of the now turned class.

```
// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
// Implementation of methods is not available
```

And now the code is not working.

The error the compiler is giving me is as follows:

```
class file for kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1 not found
```

The entire Error:

```
ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1D:\Projects\....java:143: error: cannot access Function1
                                calendarView.get().setMonthScrollListener(
                                                  ^
  class file for kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1 not found
```

If I reactivate the LeakCanary library, the problem disappears.

I really don't understand what's happening... Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Solution

[Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin in Project > Android with Gradle and choose your Java module with Single module radio button selected then select your version and OK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55742956/11214643)

### The culprit??

I don't really know, my guess is that I began using the CalendarView library, after I implemented the LeakCanary one, so the error never appeared.

Given the fact that my environment wasn't really prepared to handle Kotlin, the LeakCanary library patched some requirements, and so, the new CalendarView library began using those dependencies from the LeakCanary one.